# Share a configuration among different "server" directive

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to share a variable across different "server" blocks,

```
http {
   set $bad_ua "...";

   server {
       if ($http_user_agent ~ $bad_ua) {
            ...
       }
   }
}
```

But nginx says `set directive not allowed here`, so how am I supposed to share the $bad_ua variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to filter traffic by user agent and do something like this, in order to prevent access on some specific user agents:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* ^EirGrabber|PHPCrawl|PHP/5|^EmailSiphon|^$) {
    return 410;
}
```

**Solution**

Create a separate file that will contain the above code or any other filtering common code, and include this file on each server configuration.

```
server {
    server_name server2;
    include /etc/nginx/filters.conf;
}

server {
    server_name server2;
    include /etc/nginx/filters.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this variable ever change? If not it would be simpler to place in each server block. Otherwise you could use Lua to store the bad user agent in mysql (cached in memcached) and have each server block check for it there.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

http://blog.cloudflare.com/pushing-nginx-to-its-limit-with-lua

http://openresty.org/#Download